# Hive Generating ID

Tags: hadoop, hive

I'm trying to generate unique id's for a table that was originally done in DB2 using the following:

```
insert into database.table
select next value for database.sequence,
       current_timestamp,
from source
```

Where the sequence has a defined start value (e.g 25430).

The code I'm currently using is:

```
insert into database.table
select 
 row_number() over() + select max(id) from table,
 from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())
from source;
```

Which is fine apart from the nested select statement not working, at the moment I have to run

```
select max(id) from table
```

and put it into the query manually.

Can anyone suggest a way to do this in the one query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to force a crossjoin, something like this:

```
select 
...
from source,
(select max(id)as maxid from table) as m_id
;
```

This way you get one value for your max id back, and you can use that to generate your new one.

Generating surrogate keys with hive is kind of painful, sadly enough.